# android.support.v7 Toolbar & DrawerLayout- how to change Hamburger icon

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar, android-navigation, android-icons

My application uses ActionBarActivity and DrawerLayout and etc.
i want to change the ActionBarDrawerToggle icon to be custom drawable.

in my code i use android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar as SupportActionBar

this is my code:

```
 toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.lifeline_shield);
 setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 ActionBar actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
 actionbar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
 actionbar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.somestring1, R.string.somestring2) ....
```

but still i see the Hamburger icon, so i have my own icon for opening the drawer. How can I solve this? without using deprecated api

Comment: to do this .. you have to use custom action bar .. by using inflating

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Possible workaround:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(yourdrawableres);
```

Comment: It requires `API Level 18`

Comment: @StevieG are you sure? I think I have tried on 2.3. Will recheck