# Change Hamburger Icon in Android

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawer, hamburger-menu

I want to change Hamburger Icon and replace it with any other custom Icon.
How can I achieve this? Is it feasible?

I have go with [android.support.v7 Toolbar & DrawerLayout- how to change Hamburger icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28296849/android-support-v7-toolbar-drawerlayout-how-to-change-hamburger-icon) but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Please tell something about your code? Are you using Toolbar, Actionbar or the support libs?

Answer (score 2):

Try doing this

```
mToolbar.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Drawable d = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.id.your_drawable, null);
        mToolbar.setNavigationIcon(d);
    }
});
```

Comment: It works on the MainActivity when starting up the app, but once you click into the navigation drawer menu, the toolbar changes back to the hamburger icon.

Answer (score 1):

Use this code

```
ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,
                 mDrawerLayout, null, your_drawable, your_drawable);
```

Refer this link: 
[How to replace the hamburger icon used for ActionBarToggle on Android Toolbar with a custom drawable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27028571/how-to-replace-the-hamburger-icon-used-for-actionbartoggle-on-android-toolbar-wi)

Or, you can use:

```
mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
mDrawerToggle.setHomeAsUpIndicator(drawable_name);
```